# Are Flask client side session stateless?

Tags: rest, flask

From what i've researched, Flask's sessions are by default on the client side. Wouldn't this mean that Flask by default is stateless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Flask is not stateless, it has a [built-in session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions) implementation to hold state.

> In addition to the request object there is also a second object called session which allows you to **store information specific to a user** from one request to the next.

Sessions by definition hold state.  Wikipedia [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29)

> HTTP sessions, which allow **associating information with individual** visitors

> Cookies were designed to be a reliable mechanism for websites to **remember stateful information**

The HTTP request/response cycle, on it's own, is stateless.  You use a session to persist state across requests.  The form this session takes, whether it's a cookie stored client side, or a token to data stored server side, does not change the fact that a session is state.

[Flask provides a way to override how sessions are handled.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#session-interface)  There are various extensions such as Flask-Login and Flask-Session which provide alternative ways to handle this, such as with a token and server-side session rather than the default cookie.